# Gitlab - SSH key issues - Unable to use SSH to clone the repository

Tags: git, ssh, git-clone

We have many repositories in GITLab and we have enabled both HTTP and SSH for cloning the repositories.

Now HTTP is working fine for cloning the repositories whereas the SSH is not working and it gives the error as below.

> ssh: connect to host  port 22:Connection timed out
>   fatal : Could not read from remote repository
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Can you please help?

Comment: The first line of the error message comes from the underlying SSH library and it says that either the SSH daemon is not running on the GitLab server or the firewall (of the GitLab server) blocks the external connections to the SSH port (22). The other lines are from Git and they can be safely ignored until you solve the connectivity issue describe in the first line. They will, most probably, go away when Git can successfully connect to the server.

Comment: Have you followed their instructions on how to set up SSH access?

Comment: When i provide ssh -T -p git@hostname it provides the message as below. ssh: connect to host <hostname> port 22 : Connection timed out

Comment: @Shalini Did you get a solution for this, I'm getting same error.